# Set obtained value to Datagridview Parent/Child Form VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, datagridview, parent

I'm trying to pass a variable from a child form that contains a DataGridView, I'm calling a function to do the action, but I can not succeed alone function gets the value but does not alter the form's datagridview father, the code I'm using is:

Invoice_new (Parent FORM):

```
Controls:
DatagridView: invoice_items

Public WriteOnly Property ValueFromChild() As String
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        MsgBox(Value) 'Work
        With Me.invoice_items
            .Rows.Add() 'Does not WORK
            .Item(0, 0).Value() = Value 'Does not WORK
        End With
    End Set
End Property
```

invoice_new_search_item (Child FORM)

```
Controls:
DatagridView: search_items

invoice_new.ValueFromChild() = search_items.Item(0, current_row).Value
```

Comment: Have you tried to put the Value into DataGridView.DataSource instead of DataGridView itself? I presume you're using a DataSet or DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [CType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/4x2877xb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Funcion:

```
CType(your_parent_form.ActiveMdiChild, your_childform).invoice_items.Item(0, 0).Value
```